# Why did w32tm /resync cause it to correct itself, then overshoot?

Tags: windows, domain-controller, time, time-synchronization

#### Background:

My LAN's Windows Server 2012 R2 Domain Controller had been running without any external time server for a few years and I finally synchronized it now. It had been running about 2 minutes behind what it should be. Here's the command-line on the DC:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>w32tm /stripchart /computer:time.windows.com
Tracking time.windows.com [13.65.245.138:123].
The current time is 2018-09-10 13:28:32.
13:28:32 d:+00.1093953s o:+106.2069632s  [                           |                          @]
13:28:34 d:+00.0622590s o:+106.1968684s  [                           |                          @]
13:28:36 ^C
```

Observe the `o:+106` values, indicating this computer is 106 seconds behind what `time.windows.com` was returning.

I reconfigured it thusly:

```
w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:"time.windows.com,0x1" /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:yes /update
```

And now `w32tm /stripchart` displays the correct time:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>w32tm /stripchart /computer:time.windows.com
Tracking time.windows.com [13.65.245.138:123].
The current time is 2018-09-10 13:33:34.
13:33:34 d:+00.0781640s o:-00.0007568s  [                           *                           ]
13:33:36 d:+00.0781226s o:+00.0094363s  [                           *                           ]
13:33:38 d:+00.0781165s o:+00.0109971s  [                           *                           ]
13:33:40 d:+00.0781163s o:+00.0049739s  [                           *                           ]
13:33:42 d:+00.1249971s o:+00.0221738s  [                           *                           ]
```

Observe the `o:+00.02` values, indicating the DC is now within ~20ms of the NTP time.

#### The problem:

My personal computer on the LAN, a domain member workstation is synced to the DC, so it inherited the incorrect clock.

I ran `w32tm /update` but this did not update my local computer's clock, which still had the ~102 second "root dispersion".

I know that `w32tm` takes a while to skew the clock, so I kept `w32tm /stripchart /computer:mydomaincontroller.example.com` open to see what happens (scroll inside the console output below to `13:48:12`):

```
13:43:22, d:+00.0005054s o:+106.136670s  [                           |                          @]
13:43:24, d:+00.0004627s o:+106.148705s  [                           |                          @]
13:43:26, d:+00.0004954s o:+106.137005s  [                           |                          @]
13:43:28, d:+00.0004715s o:+106.134875s  [                           |                          @]
13:43:30, d:+00.0004988s o:+106.146821s  [                           |                          @]
13:43:32, d:+00.0005307s o:+106.139592s  [                           |                          @]
13:43:34, d:+00.0005019s o:+106.139095s  [                           |                          @]
13:43:37, d:+00.0007535s o:+105.927297s  [                           |                          @]
13:43:40, d:+00.0007354s o:+104.828951s  [                           |                          @]
13:43:43, d:+00.0007817s o:+103.742545s  [                           |                          @]
13:43:46, d:+00.0007865s o:+102.642791s  [                           |                          @]
13:43:49, d:+00.0007320s o:+101.546082s  [                           |                          @]
13:43:52, d:+00.0008024s o:+100.454105s  [                           |                          @]
13:43:55, d:+00.0007654s o:+99.3528989s  [                           |                          @]
13:43:58, d:+00.0007588s o:+98.2569027s  [                           |                          @]
13:44:01, d:+00.0007654s o:+97.1527004s  [                           |                          @]
13:44:04, d:+00.0007201s o:+96.0618527s  [                           |                          @]
13:44:08, d:+00.0009005s o:+94.9689223s  [                           |                          @]
13:44:11, d:+00.0007284s o:+93.8602069s  [                           |                          @]
13:44:14, d:+00.0007848s o:+92.7715585s  [                           |                          @]
13:44:17, d:+00.0007439s o:+91.6724994s  [                           |                          @]
13:44:20, d:+00.0007593s o:+90.5664585s  [                           |                          @]
13:44:23, d:+00.0007368s o:+89.4831227s  [                           |                          @]
13:44:26, d:+00.0007447s o:+88.3853008s  [                           |                          @]
13:44:29, d:+00.0007927s o:+87.2853882s  [                           |                          @]
13:44:32, d:+00.0014306s o:+86.1826024s  [                           |                          @]
13:44:35, d:+00.0007676s o:+85.0888854s  [                           |                          @]
13:44:39, d:+00.0006994s o:+83.9959068s  [                           |                          @]
13:44:42, d:+00.0007425s o:+82.8974550s  [                           |                          @]
13:44:45, d:+00.0008042s o:+81.7985327s  [                           |                          @]
13:44:48, d:+00.0007711s o:+80.6964513s  [                           |                          @]
13:44:51, d:+00.0007447s o:+79.6006962s  [                           |                          @]
13:44:54, d:+00.0006940s o:+78.5088182s  [                           |                          @]
13:44:57, d:+00.0011122s o:+77.4025070s  [                           |                          @]
13:45:00, d:+00.0007742s o:+76.3107419s  [                           |                          @]
13:45:03, d:+00.0007566s o:+75.2144979s  [                           |                          @]
13:45:06, d:+00.0007527s o:+74.1133596s  [                           |                          @]
13:45:10, d:+00.0006337s o:+73.0224708s  [                           |                          @]
13:45:13, d:+00.0007905s o:+71.9189507s  [                           |                          @]
13:45:16, d:+00.0014890s o:+70.8245257s  [                           |                          @]
13:45:19, d:+00.0007905s o:+69.7305667s  [                           |                          @]
13:45:22, d:+00.0007772s o:+68.6362814s  [                           |                          @]
13:45:25, d:+00.0007734s o:+67.5348673s  [                           |                          @]
13:45:28, d:+00.0007698s o:+66.4317496s  [                           |                          @]
13:45:31, d:+00.0007720s o:+65.3373735s  [                           |                          @]
13:45:34, d:+00.0007804s o:+64.2428301s  [                           |                          @]
13:45:37, d:+00.0007918s o:+63.1449978s  [                           |                          @]
13:45:41, d:+00.0007857s o:+62.0499115s  [                           |                          @]
13:45:44, d:+00.0007284s o:+60.9480690s  [                           |                          @]
13:45:47, d:+00.0012708s o:+59.8517536s  [                           |                          @]
13:45:50, d:+00.0007579s o:+58.7505085s  [                           |                          @]
13:45:53, d:+00.0037715s o:+57.6545484s  [                           |                          @]
13:45:56, d:+00.0006672s o:+56.5706047s  [                           |                          @]
13:45:59, d:+00.0007557s o:+55.4594937s  [                           |                          @]
13:46:02, d:+00.0007200s o:+54.3766916s  [                           |                          @]
13:46:05, d:+00.0006849s o:+53.2666784s  [                           |                          @]
13:46:08, d:+00.0007134s o:+52.1778095s  [                           |                          @]
13:46:12, d:+00.0007328s o:+51.0857880s  [                           |                          @]
13:46:15, d:+00.0007170s o:+49.9836731s  [                           |                          @]
13:46:18, d:+00.0007619s o:+48.8915497s  [                           |                          @]
13:46:21, d:+00.0007891s o:+47.7894672s  [                           |                          @]
13:46:24, d:+00.0007848s o:+46.6901181s  [                           |                          @]
13:46:27, d:+00.0007883s o:+45.5868773s  [                           |                          @]
13:46:30, d:+00.0007839s o:+44.4886931s  [                           |                          @]
13:46:33, d:+00.0007544s o:+43.4053996s  [                           |                          @]
13:46:36, d:+00.0008094s o:+42.2947382s  [                           |                          @]
13:46:39, d:+00.0007966s o:+41.2076924s  [                           |                          @]
13:46:43, d:+00.0008997s o:+40.1155935s  [                           |                          @]
13:46:46, d:+00.0007689s o:+39.0088370s  [                           |                          @]
13:46:49, d:+00.0007918s o:+37.9193197s  [                           |                          @]
13:46:52, d:+00.0007896s o:+36.8095748s  [                           |                          @]
13:46:55, d:+00.0006786s o:+35.7175588s  [                           |                          @]
13:46:58, d:+00.0007420s o:+34.6152128s  [                           |                          @]
13:47:01, d:+00.0007227s o:+33.5327719s  [                           |                          @]
13:47:04, d:+00.0007931s o:+32.4339650s  [                           |                          @]
13:47:07, d:+00.0007909s o:+31.3318090s  [                           |                          @]
13:47:10, d:+00.0007447s o:+30.2393576s  [                           |                          @]
13:47:14, d:+00.0008138s o:+29.1437457s  [                           |                          @]
13:47:17, d:+00.0007676s o:+28.0457416s  [                           |                          @]
13:47:20, d:+00.0007883s o:+26.9461491s  [                           |                          @]
13:47:23, d:+00.0007649s o:+25.8427590s  [                           |                          @]
13:47:26, d:+00.0007958s o:+24.7448775s  [                           |                          @]
13:47:29, d:+00.0007896s o:+23.6572525s  [                           |                          @]
13:47:32, d:+00.0007790s o:+22.5522966s  [                           |                          @]
13:47:35, d:+00.0007214s o:+21.4532253s  [                           |                          @]
13:47:38, d:+00.0008226s o:+20.3563652s  [                           |                          @]
13:47:41, d:+00.0007892s o:+19.2598154s  [                           |                          @]
13:47:45, d:+00.0014072s o:+18.1705858s  [                           |                          @]
13:47:48, d:+00.0007874s o:+17.0739438s  [                           |                          @]
13:47:51, d:+00.0007852s o:+15.9732302s  [                           |                          @]
13:47:54, d:+00.0008063s o:+14.8770975s  [                           |                          @]
13:47:57, d:+00.0007438s o:+13.7800971s  [                           |                          @]
13:48:00, d:+00.0007592s o:+12.6852783s  [                           |                          @]
13:48:03, d:+00.0007504s o:+11.5794419s  [                           |                          @]
13:48:06, d:+00.0007945s o:+10.4884036s  [                           |                          @]
13:48:09, d:+00.0007284s o:+09.3837856s  [                           |                         * ]
13:48:12, d:+00.0008046s o:+08.2928605s  [                           |                      *    ]
13:48:16, d:+00.0007786s o:+07.1999294s  [                           |                   *       ]
13:48:19, d:+00.0007918s o:+06.1020690s  [                           |                *          ]
13:48:22, d:+00.0007755s o:+04.9987732s  [                           |             *             ]
13:48:25, d:+00.0008050s o:+03.9116931s  [                           |          *                ]
13:48:28, d:+00.0022462s o:+02.7994469s  [                           |       *                   ]
13:48:31, d:+00.0008183s o:+01.7082490s  [                           |    *                      ]
13:48:34, d:+00.0007896s o:+00.6100597s  [                           | *                         ]
13:48:37, d:+00.0007954s o:-00.4889544s  [                          *|                           ]
13:48:40, d:+00.0008032s o:-01.5803174s  [                       *   |                           ]
13:48:43, d:+00.0008090s o:-02.6780945s  [                    *      |                           ]
13:48:47, d:+00.0007856s o:-03.7791214s  [                 *         |                           ]
13:48:50, d:+00.0007839s o:-04.8662262s  [              *            |                           ]
13:48:53, d:+00.0007861s o:-05.9760549s  [           *               |                           ]
13:48:56, d:+00.0008121s o:-07.0592479s  [        *                  |                           ]
13:48:59, d:+00.0007909s o:-08.1615378s  [     *                     |                           ]
13:49:02, d:+00.0007636s o:-09.2653625s  [  *                        |                           ]
13:49:05, d:+00.0007478s o:-10.3539575s  [@                          |                           ]
13:49:08, d:+00.0007580s o:-11.4467884s  [@                          |                           ]
13:49:11, d:+00.0007984s o:-12.5508851s  [@                          |                           ]
13:49:14, d:+00.0007927s o:-13.6431688s  [@                          |                           ]
13:49:18, d:+00.0007874s o:-14.7514953s  [@                          |                           ]
13:49:21, d:+00.0007429s o:-15.8458746s  [@                          |                           ]
13:49:24, d:+00.0007781s o:-16.9331431s  [@                          |                           ]
13:49:27, d:+00.0008015s o:-18.0341578s  [@                          |                           ]
13:49:30, d:+00.0007923s o:-19.1328127s  [@                          |                           ]
13:49:33, d:+00.0007342s o:-20.2368764s  [@                          |                           ]
13:49:36, d:+00.0007258s o:-21.3345439s  [@                          |                           ]
13:49:39, d:+00.0007711s o:-22.4182898s  [@                          |                           ]
13:49:42, d:+00.0007984s o:-23.5189611s  [@                          |                           ]
13:49:45, d:+00.0007483s o:-24.6187188s  [@                          |                           ]
13:49:49, d:+00.0007619s o:-25.7221868s  [@                          |                           ]
13:49:52, d:+00.0007090s o:-26.8065768s  [@                          |                           ]
13:49:55, d:+00.0007187s o:-27.9051191s  [@                          |                           ]
13:49:58, d:+00.0007944s o:-29.0071497s  [@                          |                           ]
13:50:01, d:+00.0008922s o:-30.1066847s  [@                          |                           ]
13:50:07, d:+00.0007918s o:-32.1167016s  [@                          |                           ]
13:50:26, d:+00.0007821s o:-39.0050306s  [@                          |                           ]
13:50:29, d:+00.0007328s o:-40.1024143s  [@                          |                           ]
13:50:32, d:+00.0007373s o:-41.2001761s  [@                          |                           ]
13:50:35, d:+00.0007984s o:-42.2963254s  [@                          |                           ]
13:50:39, d:+00.0007332s o:-43.3965310s  [@                          |                           ]
13:50:42, d:+00.0007456s o:-44.4922956s  [@                          |                           ]
13:50:45, d:+00.0007544s o:-45.5799108s  [@                          |                           ]
13:50:48, d:+00.0008759s o:-46.6777145s  [@                          |                           ]
13:50:51, d:+00.0007139s o:-47.7814006s  [@                          |                           ]
13:50:54, d:+00.0008556s o:-48.8813794s  [@                          |                           ]
13:50:57, d:+00.0006602s o:-49.9652265s  [@                          |                           ]
13:51:00, d:+00.0007676s o:-51.0659718s  [@                          |                           ]
13:51:03, d:+00.0007808s o:-52.1606286s  [@                          |                           ]
13:51:06, d:+00.0007777s o:-53.2685501s  [@                          |                           ]
13:51:10, d:+00.0008085s o:-54.3679582s  [@                          |                           ]
13:51:13, d:+00.0008001s o:-55.4645542s  [@                          |                           ]
13:51:16, d:+00.0007711s o:-56.5497060s  [@                          |                           ]
13:51:19, d:+00.0007777s o:-57.6471636s  [@                          |                           ]
13:51:21, d:+00.0004823s o:-58.1410037s  [@                          |                           ]
13:51:23, d:+00.0005036s o:-58.1423600s  [@                          |                           ]
13:51:25, d:+00.0005077s o:-58.1283064s  [@                          |                           ]
13:51:27, d:+00.0004903s o:-58.1394481s  [@                          |                           ]
13:51:29, d:+00.0004439s o:-58.1354109s  [@                          |                           ]
13:51:31, d:+00.0004652s o:-58.1415750s  [@                          |                           ]
13:51:33, d:+00.0004849s o:-58.1282355s  [@                          |                           ]
13:51:35, d:+00.0004695s o:-58.1418706s  [@                          |                           ]
13:51:37, d:+00.0004172s o:-58.1298115s  [@                          |                           ]
13:51:39, d:+00.0005153s o:-58.1378304s  [@                          |                           ]
13:51:41, d:+00.0004908s o:-58.1386067s  [@                          |                           ]
```

So my desktop computer decides to skew its clock to match my domain controller's... but then it just lets it keep on skewing and for the past 7 minutes it's been stuck with `o:-58.14s`.

My questions:

1. How do I force an immediate time sync without any clock skewing or slow updates: but a hard, fast computer clock reset to match the parent time source computer?
2. Why did my computer's time start to sync and then overshoot it?

#### Update:

I kept the `/stripchart` window open and eventually I saw this happen:

```
13:58:29, d:+00.0004937s o:-58.1387805s  [@                          |                           ]
13:58:31, d:+00.0005710s o:-58.1364607s  [@                          |                           ]
13:58:33, d:+00.0004962s o:-58.1399987s  [@                          |                           ]
13:58:35, d:+00.0005213s o:-58.1502970s  [@                          |                           ]
13:58:37, d:+00.0005110s o:-58.1416546s  [@                          |                           ]
13:58:39, d:+00.0004792s o:-58.1371685s  [@                          |                           ]
13:57:43, d:+00.0004684s o:+00.0050874s  [                           *                           ]
13:57:45, d:+00.0004559s o:+00.0049452s  [                           *                           ]
13:57:47, d:+00.0004935s o:+00.0010764s  [                           *                           ]
13:57:49, d:+00.0004701s o:+00.0141863s  [                           *                           ]
```

Why did it suddenly jump by 58 seconds back to where it should have been in the first place?

Comment: bare metal or VM? If VM, what technology?

Comment: @ETL My desktop is a domain-member physical computer (not a VM). My DC is a Hyper-V root partition but Hyper-V does not set its clock (and my question concerns my desktop, not the DC).

Comment: `w32tm /stripchart /computer:mydomaincontroller` doesn't show your clock, it's the DCs. Which may look extremely wobbly, because it is a VM.